# Capturar un atributo de un JSON en Angular2 - TypeScript

Tags: json, angular, typescript, rest, angular6

Tengo un JSON que se me envia como servicio externo desde esta url.
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1
Estos datos los capturo en mi angular de la siguiente manera:
Defino mi archivo de nombre Base64.ts que define la forma de mis datos

```
    export interface Base64{
    "userId":number;
    "nombre":string;
    "title":string;
    "completed": boolean;
}
```

capturo los datos enviados desde la URL en mi about.services.ts

```
import { Base64 } from "./Base64";
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AboutService {

  constructor( private httpCliente:HttpClient) { 

    console.log('servicee esta trabajando');
  } 
  getData2(){
    return this.httpCliente.get<Base64[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  }
}
```

Defino en mi about.component.ts lo siguiente:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AboutService } from '../about.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent  {

  bases =[];
  constructor( private data:AboutService){
    this.data.getData2().subscribe(dato =>{
      this.bases=dato;
    })
  }
```

hasta este punto todo normal. si hiciera un

```
console.log(this.bases);
```

tendria el siguiente resultado correcto:

> {userId: 1, id: 1, title: "delectus aut autem", completed: false}

EL PROBLEMA VIENE AQUI : No puedo acceder a un atributo especifico de esta coleccion de datos. (Quiero obtener el conteniedo de "title" y guardarlo en una variable)

he probado con :

```
console.log(this.bases[2]);
```

resultandome en consola **undefined**, tambien probe con:

```
var variable1 = this.bases.title;
     console.log(variable1);
```

esta ves me aparece un error en la consola de comandos de Angular

> ERROR in src/app/home/home.component.ts(21,33): error TS2339: Property
>   'title' does not exist on type 'any[]'

Gracias de antemano

Comment: importe mi archivo de Base64 a mi actual ts para poder usar esto pero me sigue marcando los mismos errores. _(undefined y 'title' does not exist on type 'Base64[])_
`console.log(this.bases.title);`
@JackNavaRow

Comment: donde tienes definido this.bases ??

Comment: lo tengo en about.componet.ts

`bases =[];
  constructor( private data:AboutService){
    this.data.getData2().subscribe(dato =>{
      this.bases=dato;
      console.log(this.bases);`

Comment: lo unico que debes hacer es decir que base es de tipo array About y debe ser algo como `base : Array<Base64>{} = []`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza el JSON.parse() antes de mostrar por consola ya que  desde un servidor web tu recibes una cadena y para que puedas hacer un console.log (por ejemplo) tienes que usar un objeto de Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

***RESUELTO:***
En el servicio about.services.ts quite el : **Base64[]** de
Ya no fue necesario usar mi archivo **Base64.ts**

```
  getData2(){
    return this.httpCliente.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  }
```

finalmente en el **about.componet.ts** se definio lo siguiente:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AboutService } from '../about.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent  {

  json ="";
  constructor( private data:AboutService){
    this.data.getData2().subscribe(dato =>{
      this.json=JSON.stringify(dato);
   /*    console.log(this.json); */
    })
  }

  descargar(){
    var data = JSON.parse(this.json);
    /* console.log(data); */
    console.log(data.title);
    }
}
```

use un HTML para usar un boton que realize la funcion descargar

```
<div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">capturando excel desde json</h5>
      <p class="card-text">PARA DESCARGAR HAZ CLICK EN EL BOTON</p>
      <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="descargar()">Descargar</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: si bien te funciono  no estas usando las bondades de typescript

Comment: @JackNavaRow como podria mejorarlo. usando completamente Typescript